# filter packets of a particular process using iptable

Tags: process, iptables

I would like to know how can I filter the packets of a particular process using Iptable. I read the documentation but I am still confuse how to use `--pid-owner processid` option.

Comment: Instead of fiddling with iptables, create a network namespace + veth pair, forward from the veth pair in the main namespace, put the process (or several processes) in the namespace, and snoop with wireshark etc. on the veth pair. Simple to setup, easy to use.

Comment: What do you mean by “filter”?  “block”?  “capture”?

Answer (score 5):

Matching by PID got [removed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34b4a4a624bafe089107966a6c56d2a1aca026d4) in 2005. If your documentation mentions pid/sid options, it is out of date.

You can however match by user/group for filtering out (drop) packages:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid $USER -j DROP
```

and similarly for group using `--gid` option instead. Group is matched by process primary group.

Note that the rules are applied on first match, if you an earlier match for a rule subsequent rules won't be evaluated.

Comment: Oh shoot!! :-( I really need to get traffic of one process, modify it and forward it to its original destination. @Sebasth or any one else has any suggestion to do this?

Comment: Running process as different user or group not an option?

Comment: Is it possible to do this during runtime?  I mean without logging out etc, just by running a command

Comment: @Corey For already running process I can't think of any obvious way. Setting up a network namespace and veth pair as dirkt suggested is a reasonable solution but I am not aware of a way to move existing process between namespaces. If you want further details about how to set up a network namespace a good article to get a quick overview: https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/ for